# FromBase64String return empty string

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I am trying to send an email in a Azure pipeline with some git commit comments. Since these comments can be multiline (and azure variables don't support multiline text) I encode these comments to base64 in my powershell script task.

```
# get comments through web request
$comments_all = "some multiline text"
$comments = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($comments_all))

Write-Host "-------"
Write-Host $comments
Write-Host "-------"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=commitComment;]$comments"
```

In the next (mail) task (see below), I try to decode the variable `commitComment`, but it returns an empty string (and throws no errors).

```
steps:
- task: rvo.SendEmailTask.send-email-build-task.SendEmail@1
  displayName: 'email to me'
  inputs:
    To: 'xxx@xyz.com'
    From: 'aaa@xyz.com'
    Subject: 'Git Comments'
    Body: |         
     Comments:
     $(commitComment)
     $([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($commitComment)))
    BodyAsHtml: true
    SmtpServer: smtp.office365.com
    SmtpUsername: '$(smtp.username)'
    SmtpPassword: '$(smtp.password)'
```

I only get "Comments:" and the base64 code in the body of the email, but not the decoded string. What am I doing wrong?

if I use

```
$([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("YmxhaGJsYWg=")))
```

...I get "blahblah"

Side question: is there any way to test this setup without having to run the whole pipeline over and over again to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of trial and error, this worked:

```
$([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("$(commitComment)")))
```

note the double quotes and the extra parentheses...

Comment: Hi, very appreciate this answer shared here! You can accept this answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works:-) Thanks in advance

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT done. Do you have any idea how I could test/debug these kind of things? Now I have to run the whole pipeline each time which is quite inconvenient...